# Python csv file sorting

Tags: python, list, sorting, csv, random

I am trying to build a game which involves the use of a csv file. I have a column with questions, and columns with answer, and a column which displays the position [#] value of the correct answer for each row. How can I have python sort these to ask a random question out of the rows, and use the value given in one of the columns to have a correct answer?

Comment: what have you tried? what doesn't work? otherwise, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Initialize a list list_ to [].  Then iterate over the values in the csv, appending them to list_.  Then use random.choice(list_).

Comment: Please show an example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why sort them if you're going to select one at random, and even if so, in what order or by what column should they be sorted?